# McNemar's test in Python and comparison of classification machine learning models

Tags: python, machine-learning, statistics, classification, text-classification

Is there a good McNemar's test implemented in Python? I don't see it anywhere in Scipy.stats or Scikit-Learn. I may have overlooked some other good packages. Please recommend.

McNemar's Test is almost THE test for comparing two classification algorithms/models given a holdout test set (not through K-fold or resampling method to mimic a test set). Two common alternatives are: t-test for comparing directly true positive proportions `p_A` and `p_B` from two algorithms and models `A` and `B` by 1) assuming variances follow binomial distributions or 2) estimating variances using repetitive resampling train and test sets.

The latter two, however, have been shown having high Type-1 errors (claims models are statistically different but in essence they are the same). McNemar's test is still considered the best if comparing two classification algorithms or models. See [Dietterich10](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwii54DM3LPRAhWHgFQKHR5ZAqMQFggkMAE&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.cs.iastate.edu%2F~honavar%2Fdietterich98approximate.pdf&usg=AFQjCNFoEqZMm7DktvpNO0T88xZJs8AMgA&bvm=bv.142059868,d.cGw).

Or as an alternative, how do people statistically compare two classification models in practice if not by McNemar's test?

Comment: Better try crossvalidated..!

Comment: StatsModels has McNemar's test, see [docs](http://statsmodels.sourceforge.net/devel/generated/statsmodels.sandbox.stats.runs.mcnemar.html).

Comment: @rpd Not sure if I understand. Do you mean running cross-validation? Once you get some numbers, say 72.01% and 72.22%, how do you know which one is actually (statistically significantly) better or just pure luck?

Comment: @UlrichStern Awesome! Missed that package in my survey!

Comment: i mean post on crossvalidated site of stack because here you are rather irrelevant

Comment: Just in case further people looking for this. There is a library that includes this test which includes the McNemar's test from http://www.statsmodels.org/devel/generated/statsmodels.sandbox.stats.runs.mcnemar.html. Check this one as well http://rasbt.github.io/mlxtend/user_guide/evaluate/mcnemar/