# Compare whether the difference between performance accuracy of 2 ML models is Statistically Significant or Not

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, statistics, cross-validation

This is my first time using stack exchange but I need help with a problem (It is not a homework or assignment problem):

I have two Decision Trees: `D1 = DecisionTreeClassifier(max_depth=4,criterion = 'entropy',random_state=1)` and  `D2 = DecisionTreeClassifier(max_depth=8,criterion = 'entropy',random_state=1)`. When I performed 5 fold cross validation on both of them for a given set of features and corresponding labels, I found their average validation accuracy over the 5 folds as 0.59 and 0.57 respectively. How do I determine whether the difference between their performances is statistically significant or not? (P.S. we're to use significance level = 0.01).

Do state if any information or term of significance is missing here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a very good question, and the answer proves to be not that straightforward.

Instinctively, most people would tend to recommend a [Student's paired t-test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Student%27s_t-test#Paired_samples); but, as explained in the excellent post [Statistical Significance Tests for Comparing Machine Learning Algorithms](https://machinelearningmastery.com/statistical-significance-tests-for-comparing-machine-learning-algorithms/) of Machine Learning Mastery, this test is not actually suited for this case, as its assumptions are in fact violated:

> In fact, this [Student's t-test] is a common way to compare
>   classifiers with perhaps hundreds of published papers using this
>   methodology.
>
> The problem is, a key assumption of the paired Student’s t-test has
>   been violated.
>
> Namely, the observations in each sample are not independent. As part
>   of the k-fold cross-validation procedure, a given observation will be
>   used in the training dataset (k-1) times. This means that the
>   estimated skill scores are dependent, not independent, and in turn
>   that the calculation of the t-statistic in the test will be
>   misleadingly wrong along with any interpretations of the statistic and
>   p-value.

The article goes on to recommend the McNemar's test (see also [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41539164/mcnemars-test-in-python-and-comparison-of-classification-machine-learning-model), now closed, SO question), which is implemented in the [statsmodels](http://www.statsmodels.org/devel/generated/statsmodels.sandbox.stats.runs.mcnemar.html) Python package. I will not pretend to know anything about it and I have never used it, so you might need to do a further digging by yourself here...

Nevertheless, as reported by the aforementioned post, a Student's t-test can be a "last resort" approach:

> It’s an option, but it’s very weakly recommended.

and this is what I am going to demonstrate here; use it with caution.

To start with, you will need not only the averages, but the actual values of your performance metric in each one of the k-folds of your cross-validation. This is not exactly trivial in scikit-learn, but I have recently answered a relevant question on [Cross-validation metrics in scikit-learn for each data split](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54201464/cross-validation-metrics-in-scikit-learn-for-each-data-split/54202609#54202609), and I will adapt the answer here using scikit-learn's Boston dataset and two decision tree regressors (you can certainly adapt these to your own exact case):

```
from sklearn.model_selection import KFold
from sklearn.datasets import load_boston
from sklearn.metrics import mean_absolute_error
from sklearn.tree import DecisionTreeRegressor

X, y = load_boston(return_X_y=True)
n_splits = 5
kf = KFold(n_splits=n_splits, shuffle=True)
model_1 = DecisionTreeRegressor(max_depth = 4, criterion='mae',random_state=1)
model_2 = DecisionTreeRegressor(max_depth = 8, criterion='mae', random_state=1)

cv_mae_1 = []
cv_mae_2 = []

for train_index, val_index in kf.split(X):
    model_1.fit(X[train_index], y[train_index])
    pred_1 = model_1.predict(X[val_index])
    err_1 = mean_absolute_error(y[val_index], pred_1)
    cv_mae_1.append(err_1)

    model_2.fit(X[train_index], y[train_index])
    pred_2 = model_2.predict(X[val_index])
    err_2 = mean_absolute_error(y[val_index], pred_2)
    cv_mae_2.append(err_2)
```

`cv_mae_1` contains the values of our metric (here mean absolute error - MAE) for each of the 5 folds of our 1st model:

```
cv_mae_1
# result:
[3.080392156862745,
 2.8262376237623767,
 3.164851485148514,
 3.5514851485148515,
 3.162376237623762]
```

and similarly `cv_mae_2` for our 2nd model:

```
cv_mae_2
# result
[3.1460784313725494,
 3.288613861386139,
 3.462871287128713,
 3.143069306930693,
 3.2490099009900986]
```

Having obtained these lists, it is now straightforward to calculate the paired t-test statistic along with the corresponding p-value, using the respective method of [scipy](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.ttest_rel.html):

```
from scipy import stats
stats.ttest_rel(cv_mae_1,cv_mae_2)
# Ttest_relResult(statistic=-0.6875659723031529, pvalue=0.5295196273427171)
```

where, in our case, the huge p-value means that there is **not** a statistically significant difference between the means of our MAE metrics.

Hope this helps - do not hesitate to dig deeper by yourself...

Comment: Regrets for the delay in response, but your post was increadibly helpful. I used the paired t-test statistic to ascertain the statistical significance of the difference between the means of my models and so far they have proven to be quite effective.

Comment: @desertnaut thanks for the links and answer. A follow-up question: What if I have more than 2 models to compare ? I actually have 4 models and I want to see which models are significantly better/worse than the others ? In this case, should I repeat the same experiment for each possible pair ?  (i.e. compare model1-model2, model1-model3, model1-model4, model2-model3 and so on)